# Resume several suspendEvents on Observable in Ext.js 4.2

Tags: extjs

I have a Store with items. The store can receive several `suspendEvents(true)` and this will add to a counter each time it's called.

Example:

```
var myStore = //get store from somewhere
// myStore.eventsSuspended is 0

myStore.suspendEvents(true);
// myStore.eventsSuspended is 1

myStore.suspendEvents(true);
// myStore.eventsSuspended is 2
```

To resume events on the store `resumeEvents()` has to be called twice. I've been looking around in the docs. but can't find a clean way to call `resumeEvents()` and resume all events.

One of the solutions right know is:

```
do {
        myStore.resumeEvents();
    }
while (myStore.eventsSuspended > 0);
```

But it feels unsafe since if they change how this works in a later release this might cause unwanted behaviours that is hard to debug.

Any one got an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed dangerous, your loop may call resume events when another piece of code, layout manager for example has suspended them.

you need to ensure you call resumeevents for every call you make to suspend them.  It's built that way because of the modular approach in the ext code so that events won't resume until all pieces that have suspended events have triggered a resume.